Configure raid1 on working linux
I have to create a raid1 software on a working AlmaLinux OS.
Server has 2 disks, the first (sda) with OS installed and the second (sdb) empty.
What's the right procedure to do that?
I was thinking something like this:

with output of mdadm --detail --scan I create mdadm.conf file

I copy gpt on empty disk with:
sgdisk --backup=/home/sdb.gpt /dev/sda
sgdisk --load-backup=/home/sda.gpt /dev/sdb
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb (to generate new UUID)

I add the arrays with mdadm and I set them faulty

I install the boot loader on new disk


Is this procedure correct?

It's unknown how the storage is laid out currently; that dictates what should be done and that is needed to know whether the procedure is correct. Please, add actual lsblk and mdadm --scan --detail output into the question. For now, at least I don't see a step where you actually add members into arrays.

Hi Nikita, thanks for your reply. I don't have more details, because I ordered a server in a web farm and the supplier tells me that if I want the NVMe disk I have to install raid myself. They will give me the server with AlmaLinux installed on one disk and the second disk empty. I usually configure the raid when I install Linux, so I would like to know how to configure the raid in this situation

Just edit the question and add the the output of said commands there. Without that I can assume the "default" layout without RAID, and assume "default" device names, and it'll be your problem to figure out what's different in your case and how to apply the instructions. You even didn't specify what version of almalinux. And no, if there are no prior RAID, the procedure is not correct, it misses a few essential steps: creation of arrays, move of the running system, addition of former devices into array; also the boot loader step is not that easy, because we even don't know whether it uses UEFI.

HI. The problem is that I don't have the server yet, I just know that they will provide it to me without raid 1 if I choose NVMe disks. I didn't want a sequence of commands but to understand the logic of the process. As regards the creation of the arrays, I indicated it in step 3. The bios is definitely UEFI, the Alma distro is the last, 9.4. In any case, I chose SATA disks and so the supplier will give me the server with the raid configured, I'm still curious to know what the general process is for creating a raid 1 on an already installed Linux with an empty disk

If you want to understand the logic, that's the best! I suggest you to google "how to convert a linux system to a software raid" and try it on the virtual machine. And if something went wrong, you'll have a concrete question to ask, so come back here (or, possibly, to unix.stackexchange.com) and ask, with all the details. And if everything went normal, it'll be congrats, you did it! Seriously, this is truly a good way to gain experience and understanding without breaking anything important. In the present form, the question is too broad and open-ended to answer it here on ServerFault.
